# T-SQL error Could not find stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Just wondering any one can help me with this T-SQL script, error code below. As my expertise in SQL is very limited I am not sure if this means that store procedure is missing or something actually wrong with the script.

```
 EXEC isp_ALTER_INDEX 
    @dbName = 'MODEV', 
    @statsMode = 'SAMPLED', 
    @defragType = 'REBUILD',
    @minFragPercent = 5,
    @maxFragPercent = 100,
    @minRowCount = 1000000,
    @logHistory = 1,
    @sortInTempdb = 1
```

Error

> Executed as user: Could not find stored procedure 'isp_ALTER_INDEX'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 2812). The step failed.

Answer (score 3):

you should first create the procedure before calling it, by below code:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[isp_ALTER_INDEX]
(
    @dbName sysname, 
    @statsMode varchar(8) = 'SAMPLED', 
    @defragType varchar(10) = 'REORGANIZE', 
    @minFragPercent int = 25, 
    @maxFragPercent int = 100, 
    @minRowCount int = 0
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

IF @statsMode NOT IN ('LIMITED', 'SAMPLED', 'DETAILED')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('@statsMode must be LIMITED, SAMPLED or DETAILED', 16, 1)
    RETURN
END

IF @defragType NOT IN ('REORGANIZE', 'REBUILD')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('@defragType must be REORGANIZE or REBUILD', 16, 1)
    RETURN
END

DECLARE 
    @i int, @objectId int, @objectName sysname, @indexId int, @indexName sysname, 
    @schemaName sysname, @partitionNumber int, @partitionCount int,
    @sql nvarchar(4000), @edition int, @parmDef nvarchar(500), @allocUnitType nvarchar(60),
    @indexType nvarchar(60), @online bit, @disabled bit, @dataType nvarchar(128),
    @charMaxLen int

SELECT @edition = CONVERT(int, SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition'))

SELECT 
    IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) AS FragIndexId, 
    [object_id] AS ObjectId, 
    index_id AS IndexId, 
    avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS FragPercent, 
    record_count AS RecordCount, 
    partition_number AS PartitionNumber,
    index_type_desc AS IndexType,
    alloc_unit_type_desc AS AllocUnitType,
    0 AS Online
INTO #FragIndex
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(@dbName), NULL, NULL, NULL, @statsMode)
WHERE 
    avg_fragmentation_in_percent > @minFragPercent AND 
    avg_fragmentation_in_percent < @maxFragPercent AND 
    index_id > 0
ORDER BY ObjectId

-- LIMITED does not include data for record_count
IF @statsMode IN ('SAMPLED', 'DETAILED')
    DELETE FROM #FragIndex
    WHERE RecordCount < @minRowCount

-- Developer and Enterprise have the ONLINE = ON option for REBUILD
-- Indexes, including indexes on global temp tables, can be rebuilt online with the following exceptions:
-- Disabled indexes, XML indexes, Indexes on local temp tables, Partitioned indexes,
-- Clustered indexes if the underlying table contains LOB data types,
-- Nonclustered indexes that are defined with LOB data type columns
IF @defragType = 'REBUILD' AND @edition = 3
BEGIN
    UPDATE #FragIndex
    SET Online = 1

    UPDATE #FragIndex
    SET Online = 
            CASE
                WHEN IndexType = 'XML INDEX' THEN 0
                WHEN IndexType = 'NONCLUSTERED INDEX' AND AllocUnitType = 'LOB_DATA' THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END

    -- we can't determine if the indexes are disabled or partitioned yet,
    -- so we'll need to figure that out during the loop
    -- we also have to figure out if the table contains lob_data when
    -- a clustered index exists during the loop
END

SELECT @i = MIN(FragIndexId) 
FROM #FragIndex

SELECT 
    @objectId = ObjectId, 
    @indexId = IndexId, 
    @partitionNumber = PartitionNumber,
    @indexType = IndexType,
    @online = Online
FROM #FragIndex
WHERE FragIndexId = @i

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = '
        SELECT @objectName = o.[name], @schemaName = s.[name]
        FROM ' + @dbName + '.sys.objects o
        JOIN ' + @dbName + '.sys.schemas s 
        ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
        WHERE o.[object_id] = @objectId'

    SET @parmDef = N'@objectId int, @objectName sysname OUTPUT, @schemaName sysname OUTPUT'

    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @sql, @parmDef, @objectId = @objectId, 
        @objectName = @objectName OUTPUT, @schemaName = @schemaName OUTPUT

    IF @indexType = 'CLUSTERED INDEX'
    BEGIN
        -- can't use online option if index is clustered and table contains following 
        -- data types: text, ntext, image, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max) or xml
        -- CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH column will equal -1 for max size or xml
        SET @sql = '
            SELECT @online = 0
            FROM ' + @dbName + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
            WHERE    TABLE_NAME = @objectName AND
                    (DATA_TYPE IN (''text'', ''ntext'', ''image'') OR 
                    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1)'

        SET @parmDef = N'@objectName sysname, @online bit OUTPUT'

        EXEC sp_executesql 
            @sql, @parmDef, @objectName = @objectName, @online = @online OUTPUT
    END

    SET @sql = '
        SELECT @indexName = [name], @disabled = is_disabled
        FROM ' + @dbName + '.sys.indexes
        WHERE [object_id] = @objectId AND index_id = @indexId'

    SET @parmDef = N'
        @objectId int, @indexId int, @indexName sysname OUTPUT, @disabled bit OUTPUT'

    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @sql, @parmDef, @objectId = @objectId, @indexId = @indexId, 
        @indexName = @indexName OUTPUT, @disabled = @disabled OUTPUT

    SET @sql = '
        SELECT @partitionCount = COUNT(*)
        FROM ' + @dbName + '.sys.partitions
        WHERE [object_id] = @objectId AND index_id = @indexId'

    SET @parmDef = N'@objectId int, @indexId int, @partitionCount int OUTPUT'

    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @sql, @parmDef, @objectId = @objectId, @indexId = @indexId, 
        @partitionCount = @partitionCount OUTPUT

    SET @sql = 'ALTER INDEX [' + @indexName + '] ON [' + @dbName + '].[' + 
        @schemaName + '].[' + @objectName + '] ' + @defragType

    IF    @online = 1 AND @disabled = 0 AND @partitionCount = 1
        SET @sql = @sql + ' WITH (ONLINE = ON)'

    IF @partitionCount > 1 AND @disabled = 0 AND @indexType <> 'XML INDEX'
        SET @sql = @sql + ' PARTITION = ' + CAST(@partitionNumber AS varchar(10))

    EXEC (@SQL)

    SELECT @i = MIN(FragIndexId) 
    FROM #FragIndex
    WHERE FragIndexId > @i

    SELECT 
        @objectId = ObjectId, 
        @indexId = IndexId, 
        @partitionNumber = PartitionNumber,
        @indexType = IndexType,
        @online = Online
    FROM #FragIndex
    WHERE FragIndexId = @i
END

DROP TABLE #FragIndex
```

Comment: do you know is their a particular place I am suppose to create this

Comment: you can `execute` above code in `SQL Server Management Studio` software